# Shibboleth SP: Logout results in "Security of LogoutResponse not established"

Tags: saml, shibboleth

I've working on getting Shibboleth ServiceProvider Logout running. But always when I call /Shibboleth.sso/Logout it will results in an error message:

```
opensaml::SecurityPolicyException

The system encountered an error at Wed Jan 6 00:24:30 2016

To report this problem, please contact the site administrator at root@localhost.

Please include the following message in any email:

opensaml::SecurityPolicyException at (*****/Shibboleth.sso/SLO/Redirect)

Security of LogoutResponse not established.
```

We have no choice to activate signing of Responses on the IdP site. So the only option is to find any configuration that we can set on the SP site. Has anybody an idea what we can do ?

Answer (score 0):

According to SAML standard, the LogoutResponse should be signed. However, quite a few IDP:s fail to accommodate the standard in that regard.

The workaround for Shibboleth is:

Add this to security-policy.xml:

```
<!-- Turns off the requirement of having signed LogoutResponses -->
<Policy id="unsigned-slo">
  <PolicyRule type="NullSecurity"/>
</Policy>
```

Add this to shibboleth2.xml, within the application.

< md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html" conf:policyId="unsigned-slo" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/ >